# Issue with displaying sample d3 graph bar chart on IE 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, d3.js

I've been referring to a sample [Bar Chart Screencast](http://enja.org/2011/09/15/simple-d3-js-pie-chart-webcast/) and I'm currently trying to see how does d3.js work on IE 8. I've copied the sample code present in the screencast tutorial and I've placed the same in this [file](https://github.com/boddhisattva/stores/blob/master/app/views/companies/company_division_stats.html.erb) in my app. Based on the [wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki) of d3 I've tried including [Aight](https://github.com/shawnbot/aight)(aight.js and aight.d3.js) in my Rails app, in my [layout](https://github.com/boddhisattva/stores/blob/master/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb) . But when I've tried hitting a sample url /companies/company_division_stats on IE 8, nothing shows up. It works well on Chrome and Firefox.

I understand that aight.js might have limited support in terms of functions wrt IE 8 browser. Is it because of this reason that my d3 graph doesn't show up on IE 8 and shows up on other browsers or is it something to do with my code ?

My [code](https://github.com/boddhisattva/stores) is present on github. Can any one please tell me in case I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For IE8, you would need to limit yourself to manipulating regular HTML DOM nodes with D3. But the example you linked uses SVG, which is not supported by IE8:

http://caniuse.com/svg

From the [D3 wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki#browser-support) you linked:

> You'll need a modern browser to use SVG and CSS3 Transitions. D3 is not a compatibility layer, so if your browser doesn't support standards, you're out of luck. Sorry!

From the [Aight github page](https://github.com/shawnbot/aight) (emphasis mine):

> Aight is a collection of shims and polyfills that get IE8 up to speed with a bare minimum of HTML5 compatibility, providing all of the interfaces necessary to do **HTML-only** DOM manipulation with d3.js (and other libraries that rely on those interfaces)

If you're looking for examples that do not use SVG, the first eight of [Scott Murray's Tutorials](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/) use only HTML. However, I think you'll find that most other examples on the web use D3 with SVG. If IE8 support is important to you, another library such as [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) may be more appropriate.

Comment: is there a way through which I can build a d3.js bar chart without svg  ?